# How to fix 401 Unauthorized Private Github Package

Tags: github, npm, netlify

I am trying to install a private Github package to a Gatsby project I'm working on that will get deployed to Netlify, but I am continuing to get a 401 Unauthorized...

When I add my token inline, or use my ~/.npmrc file it works and installs fine but doesn't work when I am using a local environment variable.

Here is my .npmrc file...

```sh
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

**NOTE**

I have also tried this with no luck -

```sh
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

How do I get my environment variable to work inside my local project .npmrc file?

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it working locally by removing the extra the last `/` from github.com (shown below), but this still doesn't fix the error on the Netlify side.

```
 - //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
 + //npm.pkg.github.com:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but I'm sure there's a better way...

The .npmrc has to be

To get it working locally -

```
//npm.pkg.github.com:_authToken=$READ_TOKEN
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

However this returns a 401 unauthorised error on Netlify...

To Get it to work on Netlify -

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${READ_TOKEN}
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

However like-wise this doesn't work locally...

At the moment I'm having to switch them out manually depending on whether I'm working locally or using it in production but as I say I think there must be a better way to do that.